# AJAX after retrieving data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery ajax to retrieve data from the database and display it asynchronously but how can I do it without having to regenerate the whole page again?  For example the PHP file that gets called when ajax fires, contains the instructions to fetch new data and in turn returns it to the handler.  Since I am trying to display rows of data, I have made new queries within that PHP.  It works but now I am stuck figuring out how to return ONLY the changed query and have it "know" to use the DOM elements that were originally there and just update the changes if any.  Is this possible?

Comment: Possible to see a snippet of the html/js for reference?

Answer (score 0):

That may not be a right design or very optimized to do such logic at client side. If you are talking about a very large datasets and want to optimize the data retrieval from database, the logic could be at server side to fetch only changed data and send to client all the data and update the entire section. For server to **KNOW** about the client updates the client can set the edited rows ids in a hidden value or param to server request and server can use its logic to fetch those rows.

Comment: No it is not a huge dataset as it only can return 12 rows of data at a time...And it has to be done with AJAX because the page that displays is done via JS in the first place via a slide in affect.  So if I don't use AJAX and click on submit, then the page would refresh and would not show the updated data until the user clicks on the slider again...